# Can I declare a global variable in xquery in Marklogic Server?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want a global variable which I can use in my different .xqy pages. Can I declare such a variable in xquery in Marklogic Server ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can declare a variable in any module. For instance, it is config.xqy.

```
declare variable $PRECISION as xs:integer := 4;
```

For using this variable you need to import this module in your work module.

```
import module namespace config = "http://your-namespace" at "config.xqy";
```

And refer to this variable:

```
$config:PRECISION
```

Comment: shouldn't that be $conf:PRECISION?

Comment: @Tamas, yes. Thank you. I've adjusted the example.

Answer (score 5):

If your application is running on a single E-node, you can use [server fields](http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/AppServerBuiltins.xml&query=server-field&category=AppServerBuiltins&function=xdmp:set-server-field) , which are sort of designed for this use case as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you need values accessible across the server, there is a library in the Marklogic XQuery Commons for storing persistent key/value pairs:

https://github.com/marklogic/commons/blob/master/properties/properties.xqy

And you may have already considered this, but you could also just simply store the global data in a document on the database and access with doc() - or eval() if you need to get to it from a different database.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.  If you need a global constant variable, the `config.xqy` method mentions in @Andrew Orlov's answer is great because you avoid any locking from concurrent access to a `properties.xml` file.

If you need a variable that can be mutated across a cluster of nodes, the `property.xqy` example linked by @wst appears to use globally assigned namespaces to embed a retrievable key and value.  Pretty clever.  However, I'm not sure how much this is meant for heavy levels of change.

The **E-node** specific variable from @Eric Bloch is good, but please also be aware that it will not survive a system restart.

I'd be interested to know how these all compare performance-wise.